# ObjectCreated:Post on S3 Console upload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

My S3 Lambda Event listener is only seeing `ObjectCreated:Put` events when a file is uploaded via the S3 console. This is both for new files and overwriting existing files. Is this the expected behavior?

It seems like a new file upload should generate `ObjectCreated:Post` in keeping with the POST == Create, PUT == Update norm.

Answer (score 1):

S3 has 4 APIs for object creation:

- [PUT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) is used for requests that send only the raw object bytes in the HTTP request body.  It is the most common API used for creation of objects up to 5 GB in size.
- POST uses [specially-crafted HTML forms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) with attributes, authentication, and a file all as part of a `multipart/form-data` HTTP request body.
- [Copy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) is used where the source bytes come from an existing object in HTTP (which incidentally also uses HTTP `PUT` on the wire, but is its own event type).  The Copy API is also used any time you edit the metadata of an existing object: once stored in S3, objects and their metadata are completely immutable.  The console allows you to "edit" metadata, but it accomplishes this by copying the object on top of itself (which is a safe operation in S3, even when bucket versioning is not enabled, because the old object is untouched until the new object creation has succeeded) while supplying revised metadata.  S3 does not support move or rename -- these are done with a copy followed by a delete.  The maximum size of object that can be copied with the Copy API is 5 GB.
- [Multipart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html), which is mandatory for creating objects exceeding 5 GB and recommended for multi-megabyte objects.  Multipart can be used for objects of any size, but each part (other than the last) must be at least 5 MiB in size, so it is not typically used for smaller uploads.  This API also allows safe retrying of any parts that failed, uploading parts in parallel, and has multiple integrity checks to prevent any defects from appearing in the object that S3 reassembles.  Multipart is also used to copy large objects

The console communicates with S3 using the standard public APIs, the same as the SDKs use, and uses either PUT or multipart, depending on the object size, and Copy for editing object metadata, as mentioned above.

For best results, always use the [`s3:ObjectCreated:*`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations) event, unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: Thanks, I familiar with the API. My underlying  question is why the console doesn't hide the implementation leakage and behave as expected from an RFC 2616 point of view.  The current behavior pushes logic into the app tracking new vs update that belongs in the console.

Comment: I don't understand why you believe the behavior of S3's implementation is inconsistent with RFC 2616, which allows `PUT` to be used for resource creation, not just replacement.  *"If the
   Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is
   capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user
   agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI."*

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot how do you propose triggering a lambda to fire only during object update events, then?

Comment: @LenJoseph there is, in a strict technical sense, no way to update an object in S3, because objects are immutable, so "updating" an object is actually accomplished by creating a new object using the same object key as an existing object.  S3 handles that by either discarding the prior object (when versioning is not enabled or has been suspended) or by marking the new version as the current version (when versioning is enabled).  These are all still internally treated as "object creation."  (New object, existing key).  There isn't an intrinsic way to identify a particular event as an overwrite.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot if the file exists already then overwriting is an update. Versioning, for example, is a feature that shows you each time an existing file is changed. I agree with Mike Summers and Len. Since I don't know if the file pre-existed I have to do additional get calls to determine if it is a new or existing file. A simple solution would be to use PATCH or POST or PUT respectively but really any solution would do. Debating if an overwrite/update/change is a POST or PUT is tangential.